# How to change fontfamily for memoir chapter style bringhurst

Tags: fonts, memoir, chapters

I am trying to change `bringhurst` chapter style's titles to `\sffamily`.  The following code works with other chapter styles (`dash`, for example), but not for `bringhurst`.  What's the difference?

```
\documentclass[12pt,ebook]{memoir}

\usepackage{color}

\chapterstyle{bringhurst}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Werner - That solution works perfectly, and I appreciate the explanation as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `default` chapter style prints it using this definition of `\printchaptertitle`:

```
\def\printchaptertitle##1{\chaptitlefont ##1}
```

This sets the title in the `\chaptitlefont` you define. However, the `bringhurst` chapter style updates this and defines

```
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \memRTLraggedright\Large\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{##1}}
```

which has no reference to `\chaptitlefont` anymore. You can probably work with the following redefinition:

```
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
  \memRTLraggedright\Large\scshape\chaptitlefont\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}
```

Most likely you would also want to update the use of `\MakeTextLowercase`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{color}

\chapterstyle{bringhurst}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily} 
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
  \memRTLraggedright\Large\scshape\chaptitlefont\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}

\end{document}
```